# Wordpress Not Saving Custom Post Input Fields

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to save a custom post type. I can't figure out why the save isn't working for the input fields listed below.

I included all the relevant code, as I can't see where the problem might be.  It seems like everything is working except for the save function (listed last).

I am only trying to save inputs where `'type' => 'singleinput'`. I haven't tried to save the `'fulltext'` ones.

Can anyone point out where I am going wrong?

```
//input boxes for custom post
$specialpage->inputs = array(
    'item1' => array(
        'type' => 'singleinput',
        'headline' => 'Page headline',
        'bullet1' => 'Bullet Point 1:',
        'bullet2' => 'Bullet Point 2:',
        'bullet3' => 'Bullet Point 3:'
    ),
    'item2' => array(
        'type' => 'fulltext',
        'promo1' => 'Promo text 1:',
        'promo2' => 'Promo text 2:',
        'promo3' => 'Promo text 3:'
    ),
    'item3' => array(
        'type' => 'singleinput',
        'quote' => 'The quote'
    )
);
```

This function is called to display the meta box.

```
    public function display_meta_box_($post_object){

        foreach($this->inputs as $item){
            foreach($item as $name => $title){
                if ($title == 'singleinput'){
                    $activate = 'singleinput';
                    continue;
                }
                if ($title == 'fulltext'){
                    $activate = 'fulltext';
                    continue;
                }

                if ($activate == 'singleinput'){
             $this->singleinput[$name] =  $title;


        ${$this->name . $name} = get_post_meta($post_object->ID, $this->name . $name, true);
        echo '<span class="meta_titles">' . $title . '</span>';
        ?>
        <input type='text' class='input_single' name='<?php echo $this->name . $name;?>_name' value='<?php echo ${$this->name . $name}; ?>' >      
        <?php
         }
    }
```

This is the save function

```
public function save_profile( $post_id,  $post_object ) { 
        if( $this->name == $post_object->post_type){
                //check if singleinput are defined for this custom post type
            if ($this->singleinput){
                        //save single line text input boxes
                foreach ($this->singleinput as $name => $title){
                    update_post_meta($post_id, $this->name . $name, $_POST[$this->name . $name . '_name']);
                }
            }
}
```

Edit: Added Save Function

```
$simplejoiner->saveNow();

    public function saveNow(){
        add_action( 'save_post', array($this, 'save_profile'), 10, 2 );
    }
```

Comment: Please share the action on which save function is hooked.

Comment: I added the save function at the bottom of the post

Comment: Try using this to check the post type `$post_type = get_post_type($post_id); if($this->name == $post_type){ \\do something }`